# How to reduce the costs of tests of an cloud app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, cloud

I want to build an IOS app (both iphone and ipad) which support iCloud and dropBox; And also I need to write tests for that.
How should I do that to reduce the cost of tests?
And is there any sample code in any language which would do that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are looking for. You can use a Continuous Integration tool like Jenkins that allow you to build and to test iOS applications. You can read this [article](http://programming.oreilly.com/2013/04/upward-mobility-automating-ios-builds-with-jenkins.html) which will give context about it. If you are looking for a cloud provider in order to reduce the costs because you don't want to buy a new infrastructure on your end, there is a provider which allow you to build/test iOS applications on the cloud. See [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Continuous+Integration+for+iOS) how you can do this.

If you just need a development environment for some time, maybe doesn't make sense to buy new infrastructure when you can rent a service for just the time you need it. You should consider what is your best choice.

You can also use Selenium as an option for your end-to-end tests.